# How do I run this code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is a ASP.NET page written in C#. I want to know how to run this code on browser. I don't have visual studio installed on my laptop. But I want to run this on my PC. Can anyone tell me how to do that ?

```
<% @Page Language="C#" %>

<!-- code section -->
<script runat="server">

   private void convertoupper(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      string str = mytext.Value;
      changed_text.InnerHtml = str.ToUpper();
   }
</script>

<!-- Layout -->
<html>
   <head> 
      <title> Change to Upper Case </title> 
   </head>

   <body>
      <h3> Conversion to Upper Case </h3>

      <form runat="server">
         <input runat="server" id="mytext" type="text" />
         <input runat="server" id="button1" type="submit" value="Enter..." OnServerClick="convertoupper"/>

         <hr />
         <h3> Results: </h3>
         <span runat="server" id="changed_text" />
      </form>




   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could convert this entirely to a Javascript/jQuery project.  Then you wouldn't need IIS or anything to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code won´t run without visual studio since it have code that must be run on the server. The only thing you can do is copy the code between HTML tag and save it to an HTML file. That will run but since you have logic on your server side your upper case wont work.
Nevertheless, you can use some online tool like https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

[DotNetFiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net). Change project type to 'Nancy'

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you are missing too many things:

-.Net Framework

-IIS

-MetaData (from a base ASP.net project)

-DLL

What you need to understand is that Browsers only run HTML, CSS, and Javascript. The page you are linking have intermedia code that should be converted to those 3 (HTML, CSS, and Javascript) by a server that interprets the C# code.

You can try Fiddle(Nancy), but you would require the missing server code you are referring on that view.